# Maximum of Tr$(ABA')$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $B$ be a fixed symmetric $M\times M$ matrix over the reals.

Let $A$ be an arbitrary $N\times M$ matrix over the reals.

I want to consider the problem of finding the extremal value of $\operatorname{Tr}(ABA^T) = \operatorname{Tr}(A^TAB)$ under the constraint that $AA^T$ is a fixed $N\times N$ matrix.

Can you give me a hint?

Comment: @Will, I believe the OP wants some restriction on $A$, as of now it says the product $AA^{T}$ has to be constant, which doesn't make sense because then the trace is uniquely determined.

Comment: If I understand the question, the answer should be `$\sum \lambda_i \mu_i$` where `$\lambda_1 \geq \lambda_2 \geq \dots$` (resp. `$\mu_1 \geq \mu_2 \geq \dots$`) is the non-decreasing sequence of eigenvalues of $BB'$ (resp. $AA'$).

Comment: @ Mikael de la Salle, My expected answer (intuition) is not exactly but something like yours (the problem arises in a physical problem I'm working);...but why? 

Comment: @dexter: it took me several reads to finally (I think) understand what the question you are asking is. So I took the liberty to remove some unnecessary information (that my $B$ is of the form $XX^T$) for the problem, and put the constraint more prominent.

Comment: @dexter: the first thing to note is that $A A'$ and $A'A$ have the same nonzero eigenvalues. Then use the inequality $Tr(XY) \leq \sum \lambda_i \mu_i$ for positive definite matrices $X, Y$ with non-increasing eigenvalues $\lambda_i$ and $\mu_i$. People in matrix analysis certainly give a name to this inequality, but I do not know it.

Comment: Work small examples using the method of LaGrange multipliers.

Comment: @Gjergji, +1...I just realize there should (and indeed there was a hidden) constraint on $A$. I have done the case for maximum, and hope will be able to find the min as well. 

Comment: @dexter, the minimum corresponds to the maximum for $B$ replaced by $-B$ (or $t Id - B$ for $t$ large enough if you prefer positive definite matrices). If you have done the maximum, the minimum thus follows directly.